# Move hood 3/8 inch low, how to mount as holes will be too close

Tags: hood

My contractor installed hood incorrectly. Now I need to lower it by 3/8 inch at right end so that it can rest on the backsplash.
Hood is 80 lb. New holes will be only 3/8 lower than previous holes.
How to do this safely? Please advise.[image]

Comment: why does it need to rest on backsplash

Comment: So you had the contractor install the hood first. If you wanted the hood to rest on the backsplash then the backsplash should have been fitted first. The other option is to fit a trim between the backsplash and the hood - often a better solution for sealing.

Comment: I agree with Solar Mike.   3/8" is so small it is not worth the work to get that gap lower. Additionally, once the backsplash is installed, the gap may be even smaller.

Comment: If only the pic was larger or had others accompanying it that show the actual issue...

Comment: If I did work 3/8 out of level, I’d be fired! To the OP: you might be able to pivot on the screw(s) on the low side. Just get a 2x4 under the loose side for support and fine adjustment. Try to find a mounting point at least an inch away from the first screw hole. (Maybe punch new holes in the hood and mount through them.)

Answer (score 1):

So, the hood was installed at an angle? such that the left is lower than the right, the left is correct height, and the right is too high by 3/8"?

Remove the hood, drill out the exisiting hole so that its walls have undamaged fibers, plug the hole with lots of glue and similar size dowel, let dry, temporarily mount to the wall at least one layer of scrap of 3/4" plywood covering the hole location, drill a proper size pilot hole at the proper location through the plywood and into the wall, remove the scrap plywwod drill guide, rehang the hood